# Populating tableview from structs instead of arrays

Tags: ios, json, swift, struct

I'm making a small project to practice serializing JSON in Swift 4 using structs... it gets top stories from the New York Times API and puts them into a table view. Currently I'm getting the data I need from the JSON and filling some arrays with the stuff I need (headlines, abstracts, etc).

Someone advised me to skip that step and instead populate the table view directly from the structs.

```
struct TopStoriesResponse: Decodable {
    let status: String
    let results: [Story]
}

struct Story: Decodable {
    let title: String
    let abstract: String
    let url: String
    let multimedia: [Multimedia]

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case title
        case abstract
        case url
        case multimedia
    }

    init(from decoder:Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        title = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .title)
        abstract = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .abstract)
        url = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .url)
        multimedia = (try? container.decode([Multimedia].self, forKey: .multimedia)) ?? []
    }

}

struct Multimedia: Decodable {
    let url: String
    let type: String
}

var storyData = [Story]()
```

And in my `cellForRowAt` method:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "storyCell", for: indexPath) as! StoryTableViewCell

    let stories = storyData[indexPath.row]

    print("Titles: \(stories.title)")

    cell.headlineLabel.text = stories.title
    cell.abstractLabel.text = stories.abstract

    return cell
}
```

When I run the app, the table view is empty and my print statement confirmed that `stories.title` is empty (everything showed up before when I was using arrays).

This is the function that grabs the data if it's applicable here, i'll scrap all the code that passes the data into arrays if I can use the structs instead:

```
func getJSON(completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> ()) {
    let jsonUrlString = "https://api.nytimes.com/svc/topstories/v1/business.json?api-key=f4bf2ee721031a344b84b0449cfdb589:1:73741808"
    guard let url = URL(string: jsonUrlString) else {return}

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in
        guard let data = data, err == nil else {
            print(err!)
            return
        }

        do {
            let response = try
                JSONDecoder().decode(TopStoriesResponse.self, from: data)

            // Pass results into arrays (title, abstract, url, image)
            for result in response.results {
                let headlines = result.title
                let abstracts = result.abstract
                let url = result.url

                self.headlines.append(headlines)
                self.abstracts.append(abstracts)
                self.urls.append(url)

                for imageResults in result.multimedia {
                    let images = imageResults.url
                    self.images.append(images)
                }
            }

            completionHandler(true)

        } catch let jsonErr {
            print("Error serializing JSON", jsonErr)
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

Do I need to pass the data back into the structs the way I was doing it with the arrays? I was under the impression that `let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(TopStoriesResponse.self, from: data)` did that already.

Comment: What does "structs instead of arrays" mean? You _do_ need at least one array, and you've got one: `storyData`. You still need that; your `cellForRowAt:` depends completely upon it! But there is no evidence, in the code you've shown, that you are _populating_ that array, or that you are telling the table view to reload once you've done that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need

```
let response = try  JSONDecoder().decode(TopStoriesResponse.self, from: data)
self.storyData = response.results
DispatchQueue.main.async {
  self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

the other arrays content is irrelevant here as you don't use them as the dataSource of the table

Comment: That's what I was missing, `self.storyData = response.results`. And of course I always forget to reload the table view. Thanks!

Comment: If I can ask a follow-up to this, how would I get the `url`  bit of the `Multimedia` struct, since that's a separate struct from `Story`?

Comment: `Multimedia ` is an array so inside **cellForRowAt** do **stories.multimedia.first?** to access the first element or loop for it if your cell has a layout to show all content

Comment: Yes, my cell has an image view for the images as well as the labels for the headlines et al. So best approach would be looping, I wouldn't be able to simply say `cell.storyImage.cacheImage(urlString: stories.multimedia.first?)`?

Comment: I'm getting an error on that line `Cannot convert value of type 'ViewController.Multimedia?' to expected argument type 'String'`. Apologies for the follow up questions I know it's slightly unrelated - thanks for your patience!

Comment: You need **if let url = stories.multimedia.first?.url { cell.storyImage.cacheImage(urlString:url) }**

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a mismatch in your data models. On the one hand, your JSON data is being put into four arrays: `self.headlines`, `self.abstracts`, `self.urls`, and `self.images`. But your table view knows nothing about any of that; it depends entirely on a different array, `storyData`. You need to bring those two data models together, if you see what I mean. Download the data, rejigger it into `storyData`, and then tell the table view to `reloadData`.